# Read Multiple Json file and sum a single key in PHP

Tags: php

I have an array($jsonFileArr) that contains around 6000 json file url. I want to get sum of all files volumes. I did it, but its very slow. When i execute this script it takes 2/3 minutes. i wanna decrese the execution time. What is the best way to get rid from this problem.

My script is

```
$totRetailsJsonTotal=0;
            foreach ($jsonFileArr as $url) {
                $retailerString = file_get_contents($url);
                $jsonRetailerArr = json_decode($retailerString, true);
                foreach ($jsonRetailerArr['data'] as $val):
                    $RetailSaleVals = $val['volume'];
                    $totRetailsJsonTotal = $totRetailsJsonTotal + $RetailSaleVals;
                endforeach;
            }
            echo $totRetailsJsonTotal;
```

And the sample of a json file format like

```
{  
  "time": 1565287200,
  "datetime": "2019-08-09 00:00:00",
  "outlets": 76,
  "visited": 70,
  "data": [
    { "rtlid": 3919079,     
      "volume": 0.02,

    },
    {
      "rtlid": 3919079,     
      "volume": 0.06,
    },
    {
      "rtlid": 3919079,     
      "volume": 0.09,
    },
    {
      "rtlid": 3919079,     
      "volume": 0.12,
    },
    {
      "rtlid": 3919079,     
      "volume": 0.62,    
    ]
}
```

and so on..

Comment: You are reading data from 6000 different URLs and processing it. How quick would you expect it to be?

Comment: If you are using PHP5, move to PHP7. That will improve performance.

Comment: Find a way to send multiple requests simultaneously (thread pool?), wait for the results, then add up.

Comment: Here is the problem to upgrade my server. Currently impossible to upgrade the server version.